# What is the "compile group" for gradle dependencies? And what do the different components do?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have included the build.gradle for the tutorial application that I am working through. Everything works with it, the only question that I have is what the "compile group" down at the bottom does, and what the different parts of it does? I was told to just copy the code, but I wanted to know more about what this actually did. (I copied the compile group from the maven repository website, so I know that it is valid code)

```
group 'PledgeToVote'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.5.RELEASE'
}
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

`compile` is a *configuration* in Gradle terminology.

Configurations have different roles in Gradle:

- a bucket of dependencies
- Resolvable: that is a dependency graph can be computed and used, for example to generate a *classpath*
- Consumable: this is how projects share artifacts and dependencies.

For more information on these topics, I recommend the [following webinar](https://gradle.com/blog/dependency-management-with-gradle-fundamentals-2/) (Note: I am a co-presenter in this webinar).

In addition, `compile` has been deprecated in favour of `implementation` and `api` for a while. See [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) for more details on this.

Comment: Interesting. The work that I'm doing for an internship for currently has us still using the compile notation. I'll have to take a look at these at some point.